# Keyboard input produces unexpected characters

Tags: keyboard-layout

I'm just starting to play with Ubuntu on a VPS. Root is fine for keyboard input, but the first user I've created gets weird input when using keys.

I've set it to 105 UK Windows PC keyboard.

- when I type `12345` I get `ertyi`
- when I type `asdfg` I get `^[124`

Like I say, weird!

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS

Answer (score 2):

**Don't worry your system is fine** and you problem can be fixed in no time. ;-)

There are many types of keyboards and computer keyboards are in general `DVORAK` or `QWERTY`. To discover which type is, look at the first line of letters under the row of numbers, it forms a unique sequence.
After you've discovered the layout of your keyboard, you must set it correctly: it is very easy! Just start Ubuntu and then follow the [official guide for the keyboard layout](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-layouts.html).

After the current user is fine and you know the correct layout, you can set your global (system default) keyboard layout by executing this in a new Terminal:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

New users will inherit this setting.

Answer (score 0):

As new user, set keyboard to system defaults, log out and back in. Seems to be a glitch with initial settings for a new user.